# Django custom registration form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a custom form where the user can also enter his name for instance but I am facing an issue, when the registration is done the name is not saved and I can't show it on the template.

here is the code

**views.py**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')

        context = {}
        context.update(csrf(request))
        context['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {'name', 'username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email'}

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.name = self.cleaned_data['name']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

**register.html**

```
<form action="/user/register/" method="post" id="register" autocomplete="off">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ form.name.errors }}
  {{ form.name.label_tag }}
  {{ form.name }}
</div>
[... other form fields ...]
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

So when I submit the form, everything works but when I try to show `{{ user.name }}` in the template, nothing is shown, why is that? (it works for the email field)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `User` object [doesn't have a `name` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) (so you are actually just saving the content of your `name` field to the object, and not the database). It has a `first_name` and `last_name` so you can either use those fields instead or you can [customize the `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) to have a separate `name` field

**Edit**

Also, just so you know, if you use the `first_name` and `last_name` fields instead, the `User` model has a `get_full_name()` method built-in which might be useful

Comment: Well, I the 'name' field is an example, I want to create a radiofield where the user can choose his gender and give different permissions between these genders, so I need to create a custom form.

Comment: You have two options. You can either specify a custom user model (as I linked to above) or you can create a `Profile` model that has a `OneToOneField` to your `User` model and put extra fields on that (gender etc.). I usually only use a custom user model if I want to change the *functionality* of the user (i.e. log in with an email address instead of username). If I want custom fields, I use a separate `Profile` model

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the Profile model is the best choice for what I am trying to do

Answer (score -5):

The User does not have a "name" field. Try:

```
{{ user.username }}
```